# appearing objects based on counter

Tags: javascript, object, slider

I'm trying to write a simple game based on counter, background is in form of images:

- every click on <kbd>→</kbd> increases the counter by one and shows next image
- every click on <kbd>←</kbd> decreases the counter by one and shows previous image

The counter operates in `[0,5]`, I tried to write `if` statement showing or hiding objects based on the counter.

The thing is that it works in three different ways, none of them is as I want:

- It shows all objects all the time
- it doesn't show any object
- or it only shows the first object and weirdly I can't move to the last slide, it just finished on one before last.

Any ideas or tips how to solve it?

```js
var counter = 0;
slides[counter].style.display = "block";

// hide buttons
function hideButtons() {
  left.style.display = "none";
  right.style.display = "none";
}

function slideRight() {


  hideButtons()
  //to stop slides on 0
  if (counter >= slides.length - 1) {
    return;
  }

  slides[counter].style.display = "none";
  counter += 1;
  slides[counter].style.display = "block";


  // after clicking on arrow, position is reseted
  //         var heroMovement = document.querySelector(".hero");
  // let oldTransition = heroMovement.style.transition;
  heroMovement.style.transition = "unset";
  heroMovement.style.transform = "translate3d(30px, 100px, 0)";

}


function slideLeft() {
  hideButtons()

  if (counter <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  slides[counter].style.display = "none";
  counter -= 1;
  slides[counter].style.display = "block";


  heroMovement.style.transition = "unset";
  heroMovement.style.transform = "translate3d(1350px, 100px, 0)";
}


right.addEventListener("click", slideRight);
left.addEventListener("click", slideLeft);

//appearing of characters
// showCharacters()

function showCharacters() {
  var girl = document.querySelector(".girl");
  var lakeGuy = document.querySelector(".lakeGuy");
  var contestGuy = document.querySelector(".contestGuy");


  if (counter <= 1) {
    girl.style.display = "none";
    lakeGuy.style.display = "none";
    contestGuy.style.display = "none";
  } else if (counter = 2) {
    girl.style.display = "block";
  } else if (counter = 3) {
    girl.style.display = "none";
    lakeGuy.style.display = "block";
    contestGuy.style.display = "none";

  } else if (counter = slides.length) {
    lakeGuy.style.display = "none";
    contestGuy.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.girl {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(700px, 30px, 0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  //display: none;
}

.lakeGuy {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(500px, 10px, 0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3affa0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.contestGuy {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(900px, 120px, 0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f838ff;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="slider">
  <li><img class="uno" src="images/zero/DSC_0732.JPG"></li>
  <li><img class="duo" src="images/jeden/DSC_0757.JPG"></li>
  <li><img class="tres" src="images/dwa/DSC_0786.JPG"></li>
  <li><img class="tretio" src="images/trzy/DSC_0793.JPG"></li>
  <li><img class="quico" src="images/cztery/DSC_0750.JPG"></li>
</ul>

<div id="emptySpace">
  <span class="opisujacyX">X to :</span>
  <span class="opisujacyY">Y to :</span>
  <span class="left"></span>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>


<div id="boxMap"></div>
```

Comment: Where have defined `slides`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

= is an assignment operator, like when you assign variables to strings, numbers, objects etc. == and === are equality operators. Try changing that in your else if's. I didn't see 'slides' variable declared anywhere.

Comment: omg I remember when I was correcting that kind of mistake to my friend and now I did same... shame on me, Thank you so much friend, it works perfectly fine:)

Comment: No worries, glad to help ;)